# Configuring the NAT 1:1 rules with pfsense

Tags: routing, nat, pfsense

I have two pfsense. One pfsense is on 192.168.0.1 and another pfsense is on 192.168.20.1. Basically I have installed 20.1 pfsense on one machine 192.168.0.180 which is in the network of 0.1 pfsense, and added the rules for that machine on 0.1 pfsense.

Now what I am trying to achieve is that the system connected to 20.1 pfsense rules should also be able to connect to the systems on 0.1 which is happening. But when I am trying to connect from 0.x to let's say 20.y it's not able to connect. Below image is the scenario.
[image]

So basically I am trying to connect one system on 0.1 pfsense rule with another system on 20.1 pfsense rule.

I am trying to do one 1:1 mapping here on 0.1 pfsense. But somehow I am not able to achieve that. Below is the picture of my current configurations.
[image]

What's wrong with my configurations ?

Is NAT only solution for fixing this problem ? What are other alternatives I can try ?

Regards

Comment: "_I am trying to do one 1:1 mapping here on 0.1 pfsense._" Why? NAT is not a substitute for routing, and it should only be used when necessary (private to public addressing and overlapping addressing). I see no reason to use NAT in the diagram.

Comment: @RonMaupin then how can I make a connection from node 1 in 0.1 to node 2 on 20.1 ?

Comment: Just enable routing. You don't need or want NAT. Routers default to routing.

Comment: Isn't there someone in your company that understands basic networking and routing of whom you could ask this?

Comment: @RonMaupin I am trying to understand this one for my own. So I need to add static routes and define destination network as 192.168.20.1 and gateway 192.168.0.180 right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Ron for directing me in a right direction. I used static routes from System -> Routing -> Static Routes. And change the destination network and gateway according to my configurations. Like in this diagram below :
[image]

You need to add the gateway this may be the internal or the external link. In case you didn't find the gateway click on `add a new one first` and configure it according to your gateway configuration. In my case I have used it as an internal link. Click save and try `ping 192.168.20.2`.
I started getting response from another node on `192.168.20.1`.
[image]

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: Estimados funciono muchas gracias por la ayuda atte. Edgar Pacosillo

Comment: @user49830 English please.